# Capturing and Storing Request Data Using Playwright for Python

Tags: python, playwright

I'm working with `playwright` in python (after giving up on a proxymob approach), and I'm trying to capture all the headers from a given request/response using the code:

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep
from urllib import request
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

async def main():
async with async_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
        browser = await browser_type.launch(headless=False)
        page = await browser.new_page()
        page.on("request", lambda request: print(str(request.method), str(request.url), str(request.all_headers())))
        page.on("response", lambda response: print(str(response.all_headers())))
        
        # I navigate to some page
        await asyncio.sleep(15)

asyncio.run(main())
```

The output I get is:

```
<bound method Request.all_headers of <Request url='...' method='GET'>
<bound method Response.all_headers of <Response url='...'>
```

As you can see, the output I'm getting isn't useful. Now if I use the "sync" approach I'm able to see the actual headers in the output. However, I'm using the async approach as I'd like to capture the data as I am browsing rather than having to hardcode the navigation (minds of well use devtools at that point).

So here are my questions:

1. How would I expose the headers in the output using the `async` approach above?
2. How would I store the said output in a dictionary?

Lambda expects a function and I've tried creating a custom function that adds the output to a dictionary, but nothing winds up getting stored (whether `async` or sync).

Answer (score 0):

I am not used to use async and I am not sure of your question, but I think this is what you want:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright


async def main():
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
            browser = await browser_type.launch(headless=False)
            page = await browser.new_page()


            # Now, we gonna expect a request, but that request we have to expect it after doing something, in my example is the navigation to google, in your example could be clicking a button or something else.
            async with page.expect_request("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") as first:
                await page.goto("https://google.com")
            first_request = await first.value
            print(f"The method of the request was: {first_request.method}")
            print(f"The url of the request was: {first_request.url}")
            print()
            print("And the headers:")
            # You can use this first_request.all_headers() as a Json
            print(await first_request.all_headers())

            await asyncio.sleep(5)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I did it with google, you should do it with your own page and knowing what should be the request url.

Here some doc: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-request